# is it possible to control a desktop application by a web application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have developed a desktop application in c# which send SMS by using an api, It has two button controls 'Send SMS' and 'Stop SMS'. This application is running on a Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 and I have assigned an Static IP also.
Now my question is that, can I access this application using a web application, means can I control both buttons functionality over web site if I create one and host is from the same server?

Comment: If you've separated your UI sufficiently from your business logic then it should just be a matter of putting the web UI over the same back end business logic that your desktop uses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make your application to listen spesific port and your web app can send requests to that IP and Port.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike said, actually you should be able to reuse the business logic codebase of your Desktop-Application.

But if this is no option, you also could use named pipes for communcation between the several processes, where you desktop application would be the server, that the wep application would connect to. 
May have a look at here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.100).aspx